# How are truth tables used in math?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

I am studying symbolic logic, and the textbook I am using *Understanding Symbolic Logic* by Virginia Klenk says that the proof method and the truth table method will always yield the same results, for first order logic. It says that in arithmetic or math, truth tables and the proof method yield different results. I am having trouble imagining how a truth table would even be used to prove things in math. And what is an example where the truth table method in arithmetic or math in general differs from the results of using the proof method in that same subfield of math?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I would even say that truth-tables don't make a whole ton of sense inside first-order logic; they're really only useful in the setting of *propositional* logic (unless we shift attention to "infinite truth-tables," which is stretching the notion a bit).

Comment: @NoahSchweber yep, that was what I meant, too, but had a brain free and wrote first order when I meant propositional logic.

Comment: IF you are referring to the statement at page 113, it seems to me that the author is introducing the *propositional* rules...

Comment: And IF the statement about "truth table in mathematics" alludes to *incompleteness*, it seems to me a WRONG way to refer to the well-know "divergence" between truth and provability in formal system for e.g. arithmetic. See page 193 for a more "reasonable" statement.

Comment: And see page 193:  "In predicate logic we can't use truth tables *per se*..."

Comment: [Turth tables don't help with mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4503325/21813).